# Laptop overheating due to heavy software lately installed

Tags: windows-7, laptop, performance, freeze, overheating

I have an hp laptop with windows 7, 64 bit.I lately tried downloading Solidworks 2015 of 7.6 Gb.  Ever since I did that i think my windows didn't support it much.my laptop has so much slowed down and is heating up,the google takes so much time to start, its just a mess.  Although i have uninstalled Solidworks but the problem is still there.I also tried restoring my laptop to a previous point but it didn't effect much.

Comment: Depending on where you got it from the installer could have had malware in with it.

Answer (score 2):

If you uninstalled the software, it's not at fault... unless some errant process is still running in the background, perhaps a left-over service or malware, from malicious installation. Use [Task Manager](https://www.pcworld.com/article/241693/how_to_use_task_manager.html) to see what is using so much CPU time.

Also check for malware with your antivirus suite, e.g. Defender.